# Обработка ошибки, когда отсутствует файл dll

Tags: c#, dll

Как грамотно обработать такую ситуацию:
В папке с прогой изначально был экзешник и необходимые dll. Какая-то из dll по какой-то причине удалена. Нужно чтобы при запуске программы было выдано сообщение пользователю, чтобы он скачал прогу с сайта заново, и после этого выполнение проги должно быть завершено. 
Сейчас сделал так:
В Main метод поместил 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;`

```
  private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;

        if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains(
            "could not load file or assembly"
            ))
        {
            Classes.MyForm.Show("", "Похоже, что повреждён или удалён один из файлов, необходимых для работы программы. Для восстановления всех файлов скачайте программу заново", Classes.MyForm.ftypes.Warning);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

Верно ли мыслю, или есть более правильный путь?

Comment: Замечание: `Exit(0)` - код завершения 0 обычно означает успех, нормальное завершение. А в данном случае завершение программы аварийное, поэтому код не должен быть нулевым.

Comment: более правильный путь: `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Фильтровать по тексту сообщения - действительно, не лучшая идея. Проверяйте, что тип исключения FileNotFoundException и его свойство FileName заканчивается на .dll